# How can I reorder divs within this container that I am looping over?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if ($('.category-sidebar')) {

    var $filterWrap = $('#filter-wrapper .filter-container');

    $('#narrow-by-list').empty();

    $filterWrap.each(function (index) {
      var $currFilter = $(this);
      var $divParent = $currFilter.closest('.filter-container');
      var divHeader = $currFilter.find('.toggle-category-header').text().trim();

      /*if (divHeader === 'Color') {
        $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
      } else if (divHeader === 'Clothes Size') {
        $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
      } else if (divHeader === 'Price') {
        $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
      } else if (divHeader === 'Product Type') {
      } else if (divHeader === 'Shop By Figure') {
      }*/

      switch (divHeader)
      {
        case 'Color':   
        case 'Clothes Size':         
        case 'Price':
          $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list');
          break;
        case 'Product Type': 
        case 'Shop By Figure':          
          $divParent.appendTo('#narrow-by-list :last-child');
          break;
      } 
    });
  }

});
```

- $filterWrap is the container that hold five side navbar items that are all divs
- #narrow-by-list is  tag that holds #filterwrapper which holds all 5 divs
- I want to be able to reorder the divs and place them inside the same container so right now they are:
- Color
- Shop By Figure
- Product Type
- Clothes Size
- Price

I want the list of divs to be reordered to:

- Colour
- Size
- Price
- Product Type
- Shop By Figure

The code above sorts the first three but can't get the last two sorted. Can you guys help?

Comment: That example is not really complicated and already has some "working" parts. Just adopt the missing ones... -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Please add proper code here. So it will be easy to debug
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, and I am here on stackoverflow after I have expended all other efforts. I need a alternative solution to add the last two categories divs after the first three divs

Answer (score 0):

sort your array before looping with `yourArray.sort()`, you can remove all previous DOM and rerender for every time the sorting changes

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer

Comment: answer must be explicit code for copy-paste porpuses only? or direction for an answer with coherent steps may be considered as an answer too?

Comment: sort() only sorts elements with first character alphabetically. If you have read my question it is not what I'm looking for

Comment: you can give it a callback like that:
`yourArray.sort((a, b) =>a - b);`